# Why would an implementation of custom static assert not immediately static assert "true"?

Tags: c++, testing, compilation, compile-time, static-assert

There're various ways to have static assert implemented for cases when a C++ compiler does not have `static_assert` built in. This is one example from Windows SDK (the other famous one is from Boost):

```
#define C_ASSERT(e) typedef char __C_ASSERT__[(e)?1:-1]
```

What I've never seen is a line like this:

```
C_ASSERT(true);
```

immediately following a static assert implementation.

Isn't it reasonable to immediately test that at least your static assert does not assert where it should not?

Why not immediately check it doesn't assert?

Comment: The place of the test code should be in unit test, not in real code.

Comment: @Jarod42: I don't understand why. You static assert lots of stuff in the actual code, don't you? Why not static assert "true" in the code as well?

Comment: @sharptooth Why should every client of the static-assert implementation be forced to pay the compilation overhead price of a single test (however minimal that may be) during every compilation? The author of the static-assert certainly has tests for it, but why leak these into client-facing code?

Comment: @Angew: Does this mean I should not have any static asserts in the widely included headers?

Comment: @sharptooth No, that doesn't follow from it. You should add all the static asserts which your code needs to function correctly. If you're implementing a super-fast cache which relies on `sizeof(int) <= 4`, certainly static-assert so. However, if you're implementing compile-time arithmetic, you should *not* include your correctness tests in your headers. Include prerequisite checks, not correctness proofs.

Comment: @Angew: How is "static assert true" not a prerequisite to using static assert?

Comment: @sharptooth It's not a prerequisite because its result is under control of the author of static-assert. `sizeof(int)` is not under control of the author of the cache library, it depends on the client's setup.

Comment: @Angew: Okay, I seem to understand the difference. What else except the compilation overhead would be a reason to not include this check?

Comment: @sharptooth Just general cleanness, I would say. If I saw such a test in a static-assert implementation I was using, I would immediately go "why the heck is it there? Is it necessary for something?"

Comment: @Angew: I see. Just for comparison, I'd be very happy to see that the folks who were crafting the library went as far as taking care of this tiny piece. Might save me a lot of pain when porting.

Comment: Uhm... so you also expect that `std::remove_reference` in the standard header is followed by a few test cases: `static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename std::remove_reference<int&>::type>::value)`, just a few cases, one for each combination of cv- ref/not ref/pointer, arrays (these can decay)? How is `int` being `std::remove_reference<int&>::type` not a prerequisite to `remove_reference`?

Comment: @sharptooth: I usually check the tests in the library to determine whether this has been *throughly* tested, not the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable to test, and have been tested by `#including` the given static-assert definition file into some test source file. Just like we craft a class, we test it using sample program, static asserts are well tested, on different compilers. Possibly there would be a build system, that will compile a file like `test_all_asserts.cpp` (*Unit-testing*), on each modification (say on each check-in).

What you get is the header file having static-assert definition, and nott hat `test_all_asserts.cpp` file.